# Remove border radius of List without overriding globally (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to create a small application. I need to use their [linked list](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked) but do not want the rounded borders.

From the CSS file, they use the following:

```
.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

At the moment, i override the classes using the following:

```
.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

The problem with this is that this makes all lists I have render no borders. Is there a way to override for just this single instance that I use it?

Here's an example from bootstrap on how to use this (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked):

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Comment: its simple | create a parent class and point it to the child class, it'll do the override for the parent class with the specified element in it like `.parent > .list-group-item {color: blue;}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you add a special class name for your `list-group` such as `list-special`? Then use...

CSS

```
.list-special .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
}

.list-special .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="list-group list-special">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/95585

EDIT: It's generally not good practice to use CSS !important. Since the `list-special` provides more specificity, you can remove the `!important`. I updated the Bootply so that you can see how this works.

Answer (score 8):

Just add an extra class to your containing div.

```
<div class="list-group special">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        Cras justo odio
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

and then target it via css:

```
.special .list-group-item:first-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
}

.special .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

EDIT:
As requested a bootply link: [bootply](http://bootply.com/95588)

Comment: quick fyi: this continues to work with bootstrap 4 (alpha), just wrap your `<ul></ul>` in the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-pers .list-group-item{border-radius: 0px !important;}
```